# How to identify what is the device name or block name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, block, volume

[image]

I've created an EC2 instance having 2 volumes attached to it, `/dev/xvda` is for the root volume and `dev\sdb` is for another magnetic volume which added.

Now when I `SSH` into the instance and try `lsblk` I couldn't find the one with `dev/sdb`[image]

since `lsblk` only returning me 2 blocks which are `xvda` and `xvdb`, I can safely assumed that `dev/sdb` was referring to `xvdb` but really what is their relation? Sorry I have very minimal linux/unix background and hence this question

Comment: Note that `sd` = SCSI disk, `xvd` = Xen virtual disk.  For all practical purposes they are two different abbreviations for the same thing, and the letters that follow should always be consistent, a = a, b = b, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AWS used to call the volumes `/dev/sdb` but now they are automatically called `/dev/xvdb` even if you attach them with the `/dev/sdb` name.

> Depending on the block device driver of the kernel, the device could be attached with a different name than you specified. For example, if you specify a device name of /dev/sdh, your device
>   could be renamed /dev/xvdh or /dev/hdh
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html

Comment: Additionally, "in some versions of Red Hat Enterprise Linux (and its variants, such as CentOS), even the trailing letter could change (/dev/sda could become /dev/xvde)"